# How can I create multiple OrchardCore decoupled sites under the same instance

Tags: razor, orchardcore

I know how to create a single decoupled site in OrchardCore. I am trying to figure out how to create multiple decoupled sites under the same instance.  Can't find a single example of this.  Just want to understand the project layout and I understand how to set up multi-tenant part in the cms.

Is there any repo or examples or creating more than one site that is decoupled, or will I need to have each site with its own cms if it is decoupled?